# Get X Y coordinates of elements within an InkCanvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, coordinates, inkcanvas

I have an InkCanvas which has it's children programmically added in through `C#`. They are not set with `InkCanvas.LeftProperty` or `InkCanvas.TopProperty`. I was wondering if it was at all possible to get these default X and Y values of the elements. Currently if I check the `InkCanvas.LeftProperty` or `InkCanvas.TopProperty` it would return `NaN` as they are not set. Is this possible at all? Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers,

Nilu

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be the answer:

`Vector vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(element);`

It returns a vector with the element offset relative to the parent. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getoffset.aspx).

Edit: Don't think this is going to help me for what I want to do. Although it's a good method if you are setting the margin on elements initially. In my case I think I would have to set the co-ordinates explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use various static methods defined on `Canvas` to get those values - [GetLeft()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.getleft.aspx), [GetTop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.gettop.aspx), etc. I believe that `LeftProperty` is just the definition of the attached property itself, not the way to get the value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However even when I used those methods the values are NaN. However I was able to find the VisualTreeHelper method which would return the offset of the element relative to the parent (InkCanvas). Which seems to work atm. Thanks for your help. :)